# How can i get the user's transfer time in public transpotation data?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have public transportation user's data. I want to find the user's transfer time. My data is like this;

```
---Media--------------Time

10010101   ---  2019-01-01 19:38

10010101   ---  2019-01-01 21:38

25757858   ---  2019-01-02 08:30

25757858   ---  2019-01-02 12:00
```

And i want to do this;

```
---Media--------------1.Time--------------------2.Time ---------Minus Time

10010101   ---  2019-01-01 19:38  ---   2019-01-01 21:38   ------   02:00

25757858   ---  2019-01-02 08:30  ---   2019-01-02 12:00   ------   03:30
```

How can i do?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Could a Media have more than 2 times? Maybe 3, 4, 100? If so, what results are you expecting then? Could the difference in time be more than 24 hours? If no, how sure are you of that "no"? Personally, for your column `[Minus Time]` I would suggest providing the values in duration; considering your times appear to be accurate to 1 minute, then the number of minutes between the 2 times (so `120` and `210` respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Declare @tab table(media bigint,[Time] datetime)

    insert into @tab
    SELECT 10010101,'2019-01-01 19:38' Union All
    SELECT 10010101,'2019-01-01 21:38' Union All
    SELECT 25757858,'2019-01-02 08:30' Union All
    SELECT 25757858,'2019-01-02 12:00'

    ;with cte
    As
    (
        Select media,[Time] as [1.Time],Lead([Time]) over(Partition by media order by [Time] desc) as [2.Time]
        from @tab
    )

    Select *,
    CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(n, [2.Time],[1.Time])/60) + ':' 
    + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar, (DATEDIFF(n, [2.Time],[1.Time])%60)), 2) As [Minus Time]
    from cte where [2.Time] is not NULL
```

If there are more than 2 rows for each media, and if you want to get the time difference between the first and last entry (order by time), try below query:

```
        Declare @tab table(media bigint,[Time] datetime)

        insert into @tab
        SELECT 10010101,'2019-01-01 19:38' Union All
        SELECT 10010101,'2019-01-01 20:00' Union All
        SELECT 10010101,'2019-01-01 21:38' Union All
        SELECT 25757858,'2019-01-02 08:30' Union All
        SELECT 25757858,'2019-01-02 12:00'


        ;with cte1
        As
        (
            Select *,
            row_number() over (partition by media order by [Time] asc) as seqnum_asc,
            row_number() over (partition by media order by [Time] desc) as seqnum_desc
            From @tab
        )

        ,cte
        As
        (
            Select media,Lead([Time]) over(Partition by media order by [Time] desc) as [1.Time],[Time] as [2.Time]
            from cte1 where seqnum_asc = 1 or seqnum_desc = 1   
        )

        Select *,
        CONVERT(varchar, DATEDIFF(n, [1.Time],[2.Time])/60) + ':' 
        + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar, (DATEDIFF(n, [1.Time],[2.Time])%60)), 2) As [Minus Time]
        from cte where [1.Time] is not NULL
```